# Chain of delegates in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

**TDLR;** I have three classes, when `Class A` object is updated, it's calling on its delegate (`Class B`) which is calling on its delegate (`Class C`) without doing anything else. `Class C` will use `Class B` in different ways depending on the values in `Class A`. `Class B` need to know of its `Class A` at touch events. Is this acceptable?

```
classA { var information: String }
classB { var thing: ClassA thing.delegate = self }
classC { var things: [ClassB] for thing in things { thing.delegate = self } }
```

**My real example**

I have three classes: A `mapViewController`, a `mapMarker` and a `place` (model). The map holds multiple `mapMarker`s, and every `mapMarker` has a property `place`, which contains information of what the marker should look like (like place type, "bar", "restaurant" etc). The place might receive new information via a silent push notification, and hence being updated. When the place is updated, I need to notify the `mapViewController` that the marker needs to be redrawn (I'm using MapBox and their annotations doesn't support redrawing in any way but removing and adding the marker again, since the `imageForAnnotation` method is a delegate one.)

My first thought was to make two protocols `placeDelegate` and `mapMarkerDelegate`.

Place:

```
protocol PlaceDelegate: class
{
  func placeUpdated()
}

class Place {
    weak var delegate: PlaceDelegate?

    var propertyThatCanBeUpdate: String {
        didSet { 
        //Checking if the newValue == oldValue 
        delegate.placeUpdated()
        }
}
```

MapMarker

```
protocol MapMarkerDelegate: class
{
    markerShouldReDraw(mapMarker: MapMarker)
}

class MapMarker: PlaceDelegate {
    var place: Place!
    weak var delegate: MapMarkerDelegate?
    init(place: Place) {
        self.place = place
        place.delegate = place
    }

    func placeUpdate()
    {
        delegate.markerShouldReDraw(self)
    }

}
```

MapViewController

```
class MapViewController {
//I could easily set the marker.delegate = self when adding the markers

func markerShouldReDraw(mapMarker: MapMarker)
    functionForRedrawingMarker()
}
```

This feels a bit ugly, and a bit weird that the MapMarker is just passing the "my place has been updated" information forward. Is this acceptable as far as performance goes? Should I use some kind of `NSNotification` instead? Should I make the `MapViewController` the delegate of `place` and search my array of `mapMarker` for the one holding the correct `place`?

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30151732/1097429), may be it helps.